# javaout typemap doesn't work for std::vector of pointers

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, swig

With `vector` of structures everything works fine

```
%include <std_vector.i>

%typemap(javaout) const S1& std::vector<S1>::get {
  //custom code
}

struct S1 {};
std::vector<S1> val;

%template(vector_s1) std::vector<S1>;
```

But doesn't work with `vector` of pointers

```
%include <std_vector.i>

%typemap(javaout) const S1*& std::vector<S1*>::get {
  //custom code
}

struct S1 {};
std::vector<S1*> val;

%template(vector_s1) std::vector<S1*>;
```

Samples were compiled with `swig -java -c++ -module sample sample.i`

SWIG version:

```
$ swig -version

SWIG Version 3.0.7

Compiled with i586-mingw32msvc-g++ [i586-pc-mingw32msvc]

Configured options: +pcre
```

Comment: What does mean "doesn't work"?

Comment: @sibnick I get default `vector_s1.get(int)` definition instead of specified in typemap.

Comment: Can you specify swig version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look in the file [`swig/Lib/std/std_vector.i`](https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Lib/std/std_vector.i) that provides language independent wrapper code for `std::vector`, you will find the following comment:

> ```
> // ***
> // This specialization should disappear or get simplified when
> // a 'const SWIGTYPE*&' can be defined
> // ***
> template<class _Tp, class _Alloc >
> class vector<_Tp*, _Alloc > { ...
> ```

So it appears that SWIG currently cannot handle the `const S1*&` in your above typemap definition.

Now, the file [swig/Lib/java/std_vector.i](https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Lib/java/std_vector.i) that provides the java wrappers for `std::vector` is much less sophisticated and lacks the specialization for `std::vector<T*>`.

Adding such a specialization yourself should solve your problem:

file `std_vector_pointer.i`:

```
%include <std_vector.i>
namespace std {
template<class T> class vector<T*> {
  public:
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef T* value_type;
    typedef value_type const_reference;
    vector();
    vector(size_type n);
    size_type size() const;
    size_type capacity() const;
    void reserve(size_type n);
    %rename(isEmpty) empty;
    bool empty() const;
    void clear();
    %rename(add) push_back;
    void push_back(T* x);
    %extend {
        T* get(int i) throw (std::out_of_range) {
            int size = int(self->size());
            if (i>=0 && i<size)
                return (*self)[i];
            else
                throw std::out_of_range("vector index out of range");
        }
        void set(int i, T* val) throw (std::out_of_range) {
            int size = int(self->size());
            if (i>=0 && i<size)
                (*self)[i] = val;
            else
                throw std::out_of_range("vector index out of range");
        }
    }
};
}
```

Then the following should work for your above example:

```
%include "std_vector_pointer.i"

%typemap(javaout) S1* std::vector<S1*>::get {
  //custom code
}

struct S1 {};
std::vector<S1*> val;

%template(vector_s1) std::vector<S1*>;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of using raw pointers, why not used std::shared_ptr?**

This code should work the way you expect it to, with your "custom code" replacing the get function block in vector_s1.java.

```
%module sample

%include <std_vector.i>
%include <std_shared_ptr.i>

%{
#include <memory>
%}

%typemap(javaout)  const std::shared_ptr<S1>& std::vector<std::shared_ptr<S1> >::get {
  //custom code
}

struct S1 {};

%shared_ptr(s1);
%template(vector_s1) std::vector<std::shared_ptr<S1> >;
```